# Why do you need to specify the kernel ID when launching and instance from an AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

To my understanding the AMI contains all the files of the system, including compiled kernel.

When you create an AMI from a snapshot you can specify the kernel ID (ex aki-*).  Why then do you need to specify the kernel ID when launching an instance from an AMI that already has the Kernel ID specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon uses Xen paravirtualization which requires a kernel to be supplied as part of the config. Xen uses the kernel in a very different way than say VMWare or KVM. It allows, among other things, for a hypervisor to run efficiently without CPU virtualization extensions.